# after building the app i am getting these error in my flutter debug console , recenty i have shifted to null safety

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

```
enter code hereNote: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.4.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
Note: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.4.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.4.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:38: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

try `flutter clean` and `rebuild`, and follow [migration](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/) package version